# How to Get non nullable Columns of a Table using java?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am trying to get the non-nullable columns of a table through a java code.... Can anyone help me?

Comment: Like any other (nullable) column. What is your problem? Why the PLSQL tag, shoudn't it be jdbc?

Answer (score 2):

It is not completely clear what you are asking. Do you want to find out, from your Java program, which columns of a specific table are not nullable?

You can call `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()` to get information about the columns of a table. One of the items that you'll get back is `IS_NULLABLE`, which indicates if the column is nullable. See the API documentation of the `getColumns` method for detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

not a Java answer, but you can query for it!

```
select 
     table_name, 
     columns_name, 
     data_type, 
     nullable 
  from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
```

supply the table_name and filter on nullable